# IComponentsApplicationBuilder type cannot be found in the Startup class of Blazor

Tags: blazor

I am trying to learn Blazor by following a tutorial. The tutorial created a singleton service in the "Client" that needs to be declared in the Startup class. The problem is in my end, I get an error in the part of `IComponentsApplicationBuilder`. This is the whole code of the Startup.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace BlazorMovies.Client
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<SingletonService>();
            services.AddTransient<TransientService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Could you please show me how to correct this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using code from the Middle Ages. Here's a code snippet showing how it looks like today:

```
 var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

[See the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-webassembly): how to do it right

Comment: Oh! I see. the tutorial is entitled Blazor and it's 2020. I was thinking that's how it should be done. Thank you.

Comment: @Ibanez1408, I'd recommend you to learn Blazor through this web site: https://chrissainty.com/ The articles and tutorials are not only good, but are updated regularly to reflect the changes the Blazor framework undergoes. You may also learn through this web site: https://blazor-university.com/