# How to get JS object and pass it back?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I would like to call JS function from Blazor (this is factory method) and then pass the obtained object back to JS (another function).

The problem is Blazor changes the object, so when I print the data of object being returned (in the first function) and the object obtained in the second function I can see the structure is different.

*I don't want to modify or read this object in Blazor in any way, just get+pass, that's it.*

**Update**: please read comment by KirkWoll for more technical rephrasing. Currently I call JS function as `await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(...` but it does not work (as expected).

C# -- Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: @KirkWoll there's definitely another question which matches better.

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed the before and after structure, or at least enough to understand the problem.

Comment: @Yogi, just to be sure as a debug measure I store the returned value as global variable in JS and then also compare in the second function if I get what I expect `arg===stored_obj` -- the outcome is false. This is enough to get incorrect results, but as the structure goes, for example the data from the argument has such line (when dumped to console) "<prototype>: Object { Symbol("wasm type"): 0, … " while original does not have it. And vice versa original has some properties which are missing in the argument.

Comment: @Yogi, I think the question can simply be boiled down to "Is there an inverse of [`DotNetObjectReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.dotnetobjectreference?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that allows an opaque passing of Javascript objects into and out of C#?"   (`DotNetObjectReference` allows your Javascript code to have a handle to C# objects.  OP wants something similar so they can have a handle to a JS object in C# that they can then hand back to a JS function with the expectation that it's literally the same object instance)

Comment: @greenoldman, haven't used this yet, but it seems [`IJSObjectReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.ijsobjectreference?view=aspnetcore-6.0) might be what you're after?  https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/interacting-with-javascript-objects-using-the-new-ijsobjectreference-in-blazor  (introduced in .NET 5)

Comment: @KirkWoll, thank you and sorry, I forgot to mention it is NS 2.0.

Comment: @greenoldman oof, Blazor is rapidly changing technology.  Hopefully you can get on a recent version sooner or later.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo and workaround**

I've created this simple [Blazor Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/iqf2o3tb) (WASM 3.1) that reads a JavaScript object and then writes it back. And if you view the output in the browser console you can see the object is passed back and forth with the properties intact.

However, the function is stripped from the object. And that's because the object is passed as json and json only has properties. So it's only possible to send properties.

OP also tests if the returned object is the same as the stored global object. Yet, that will be false because these are different instances. The properties might be equal, but not the references.

**A workaround**

If the requirement is to pass the object by reference from one JavaScript function to another then the workaround would be to create a JavaScript function to do this directly without passing the object to Blazor. Basically, just a function that triggers the call. The workaround is included in the fiddle.

**Update 2023**

Blazor Fiddle is outdated and stuck on .NET 3.1.  So when you look at the code, focus on the parts that pass the object back and forth. Ignore the App initialization parts as this has changed since 3.1. See this question for details: [IComponentsApplicationBuilder type cannot be found in the Startup class of Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61243084/icomponentsapplicationbuilder-type-cannot-be-found-in-the-startup-class-of-blazo)

Comment: Thank you. For the time being I don't see why/how you succeeded in passing object without Blazor overhead which are clearly present in my case, but your workaround is a good one.

Comment: They have updated the runtime version which requires a slight change in your fiddle to run, I have made the change, but don't want to just edit it in as it's the heart of your answer.  https://blazorfiddle.com/s/tob9guu9